# Cannot ping my local machine

Tags: macos, network, hosts, ping

I have just updated my Mac to macOS Sierra 10.12. My hostname is ninjaPixels-Macbook-Pro and if I run:

`ping ninjaPixels-Macbook-Pro.local` 
or `ping ninjaPixels-Macbook-Pro`

I get an error of *unknown host*.

`host ninjaPixels-Macbook-Pro.local` returns the error: *Host ninjaPixels-Macbook-Pro.local not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)*

This is an issue as part of our codebase at work needs to run the following python: `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` and it fails because my computer seems to have forgotten who it is.

I can successfully run `ping localhost` and `ping 127.0.0.1`

I’ve tried the following:

- Rebooting.
- Switching off the Firewall.
- Changing my local hostname, using System Preferences > Sharing > Edit.
- `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`
- `dscacheutil -flushcache`
- `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`
- `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist`

Comment: out of left-field... I've seen similar issues if IPv6 was mapped to localhost in hosts, mapping `::1   127.0.0.1` instead seems to fix it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks. I just tried modifying hosts with that but sadly no cigar.

Comment: What Sharing do you have enabled, if any?  You need to have some form of sharing enabled (or Service enabled under Sharing) in order to `ping $HOSTNAME`.  On a clean install of macOS Sierra, Firewall turned off and nothing shared, I can replicate a `ping $HOSTNAME` error. It I turn on, e.g. File Sharing, I can `ping $HOSTNAME` from macOS and `ping macOShostname.local` from OS X on the same network.

Comment: @ninjaPixel Do you have a dns server in your network, what's the search domain (in SysPrefs > Network > Interface > DNS) and finally what's the hostname of your mac (e.g. ninjapixel.example.com) if any?

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you, you solved it! I needed to enable some form of sharing. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Cheers!

Comment: @User3439894 - I am experiencing similar problems. I have an old HP Laserjet connected to my router. I used to be able to print with Gutenprint - the printer has its own IP. Since updated to Sierra it wont work. Also there is a timeout when I ping the IP. How can I add the print to the hosts file? I tried with the IP and the name of the printer...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Assuming the Firewall is turned off, then in order to `ping $HOSTNAME`, there has to be some form of sharing or service enabled in System Preferences > Sharing, **or** add an entry to the `/etc/hosts` file, depending on how/what you're trying to access by `$HOSTNAME`. Example, `127.0.0.1 computer_name` where `computer_name` is what's reported by `echo $HOSTNAME` or in lieu of `127.0.0.1` the actual IP Address of the Network Adapter on your system.

Comment: Adding `127.0.0.1 computer_name` works for me.

Comment: After turning on File Sharing `ping macOShostname.local` started to work, even *after turning File Sharing off*.

Comment: that is so weird, it worked for me for like 2 weeks and stopped working out of now where .. changing my etc/hosts file worked fine as well ...

Comment: Adding 127.0.0.1 hostname works for me. Thanks.